# Lista estática em C: Erro de impressão

Tags: c, struct, printf

Estou estudando listas lineares e praticando em C com o DEV-C++ v6.3. Faz muito tempo que não mexo na linguagem e tem muita coisa que não lembro e não sei como começar a procurar para consertar.

Adaptei um código de lista estática com dados inseridos pelo usuário e inclusão de elemento no meio da lista. Meu problema está na impressão dos dados após a adição e após a alteração.
Cada linha imprime 2 dados, nome e CPF, porém, no final da linha está repetindo o primeiro dado, nome.

Como faço para corrigir isso?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
    
struct alunos{
    char nome[20];
    char CPF[12];   
};

int main(){
    struct alunos  lista_alunos[100];
    int i;
    
    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf ("qual o nome do aluno: ");
        scanf("%s",lista_alunos[i].nome);
        printf ("qual o CPF do aluno: ");
        scanf("%s",lista_alunos[i].CPF);
    }
    
    printf ("\n\n\nDados registrados:\n");
    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf ("\nO registro %d eh -> Nome: %s, CPF: %s. ",i+1,lista_alunos[i].nome,lista_alunos[i].CPF);
    }

    
    //inclusão entre o segundo e o terceiro elemento criando um novo terceiro elemento  
    for (i=2;i>1;i--){
        strcpy(lista_alunos[i+1].nome,lista_alunos[i].nome); 
        strcpy(lista_alunos[i+1].CPF,lista_alunos[i].CPF); 
    }   

    strcpy(lista_alunos[2].nome,"Novo");
    strcpy(lista_alunos[2].CPF,"00000000000");
    
    
    printf ("\n\n\nDados alterados:\n");
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf ("\nO registro %d eh -> Nome: %s, CPF: %s.",i+1,lista_alunos[i].nome,lista_alunos[i].CPF);
    }
            
    return(0);    
}
```

[Execução do código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iXoJ.png)

Além disso, se eu alterar o tamanho do char CPF dentro da struct, o 4º dado imprime sem o nome, assim:

[Execução com char CPF alterado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geSHh.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O último espaço de toda string em C não deve ser preenchido pelo usuário, pois deve ser reservado para o caractere terminador '\0', o qual finaliza a string.

Comment: Eu não sabia disso, nunca tinha lido a respeito. Vou procurar entender um pouco mais sobre essa questão.
Muito obrigada pela ajuda, realmente era esse o problema.